# Changing the default folder for opening a new Finder tab or window in macOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, finder, high-sierra, folders, defaults

When I press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Finder to open a new tab or window, for some reason it always starts in this folder:

> /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/MyLibraries/myDocuments.cannedSearch

I know on other macOS systems it typically opens in the user's Home folder.

It makes no difference whether I already have other windows or tabs open, or if I close everything and then open a fresh new window, the above always happens.

Is there some way I can change this? Is there a configuration setting somewhere for a default folder for any new Finder window?

P.S. I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finder menu > Preferences... or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>[comma] ,</kbd>  > General

New Finder windows show:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Typically one of those "how could I have missed that" things :) (I did look in Preferences but somehow overlooked this option)